# Appending an image to the DOM only after it is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, image, css-sprites

Currently I have an `img` element that uses a `top` style to display a sprite, and would like to change it dynamically for another, non-sprite image. I'm currently doing the following:

HTML:

```
<span id="container">
  <img src="sprite.png" style="top:-40px;">
</span>
```

Javascript:

```
var newImgEl = document.createElement('img');
newImgEl.setAttribute('src', 'other-image.png'); // (1)
newImgEl.style.top = "0px";

var containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
containerEl.innerHTML = '';
containerEl.appendChild(newImgEl); // (2)
```

What I couldn't find is: **Will the image be loaded in (1) or (2)?** I couldn't test the effect of a slow connection, but I suspect that if it is loaded in (2), the style will be changed before the image is loaded, briefly showing an unintended part of the sprite. If so, how can I fire the loading and append the element to the DOM after it completes?

Please, no jQuery solution.

Comment: You might want to check the onload event for images https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onload

Comment: It'll start loading/be loaded at **(1)**, to test simply paste this into your JavaScript console: `var img = document.createElement('img'); img.onload = function(){ alert('loaded'); }; img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people/3';`

Comment: David Thomas, that was useful, I used it to create a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the image is loaded simply by changing the `src` attribute before actually appending to the DOM, I've done the following, that does not require timeouts:

```
var newImgEl = document.createElement('img');
newImgEl.addEventListener('load', function() {
  newImgEl.style.top = "0px";
  containerEl.innerHTML = '';
  containerEl.appendChild(newImgEl);
});
newImgEl.setAttribute('src', src); // Loads the image.
```

I've yet to check if it works cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is add the new image to the DOM so it can load from the server then very quickly reset all styles related to size and position.

You can set the `setTimeout` time that works best for your specific situation.

**newImgEl.style.top = "-10000px";**

```
function someFunction()
{

var newImgEl = document.createElement('img');
newImgEl.setAttribute('src', 'other-image.png'); // (1)
newImgEl.style.top = "-10000px";

var containerEl = document.getElementById('container');
containerEl.innerHTML = '';
containerEl.appendChild(newImgEl); // (2)


setTimeout(function()
{

 newImgEl.style.top = '0px';

},250);

};
```